# Display Dimension Member ID and Caption in Result

Tags: c#, .net, ssas, mdx

I'm trying to write an MDX statement where I query the Dimension Member Unique Name and Caption in my result set.

For example:

```
Member 1 Unique Name    |     Member 1 Caption
Member 2 Unique Name    |     Member 2 Caption
Member 3 Unique Name    |     Member 3 Caption
Member 4 Unique Name    |     Member 4 Caption
Member 5 Unique Name    |     Member 5 Caption
```

Using ADOMD, I'm trying to retrieve a list of members for any given dimension attribute (regardless of hierarchy right now) and hold them in an object. I'm not exactly sure how to write the MDX statement

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand what you are going for, but here is an MDX statement that gets the unique name and caption for members of a specific dimension hierarchy.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.DimensionUniqueName as 
[Dimension].[Hierarchy].Currentmember.Unique_Name
MEMBER Measures.DimensionCaption as 
[Dimension].[Hierarchy].Currentmember.Member_caption

SELECT Measures.DimensionUniqueName, Measures.DimensionCaption on 0, 
[Dimension].[Hierarchy].children on 1 
from [Cube]
```

As an example, if I have a dimension [Product] with hierarchy [Category] and 4 members:

- [Product].[Category].[Accessories]
- [Product].[Category].[Bikes]
- [Product].[Category].[Clothing]
- [Product].[Category].[Components]

I would use the following query:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.DimensionUniqueName as 
[Product].[Category].Currentmember.Unique_Name
MEMBER Measures.DimensionCaption as 
[Product].[Category].Currentmember.Member_caption

SELECT {Measures.DimensionUniqueName, Measures.DimensionCaption} on 0, 
[Product].[Category].children on 1 
from [Cube]
```

to get this result 
[image]

You can either ignore the first column, or if you don't care about the order you don't need the Member Caption since that is what is shown when you call a member by default (in other words, you don't need the third column since it is redundant).

I'm guessing you can dynamically populate your MDX statements to do one of these for each dimension hierarchy.

Comment: Your first example will be better since I will be incorporating hierarchies later on during development. Thank you for the answer!